# Try to install Autodesk Maya on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, startup, 14.10, error-handling

I try to install Autodesk Maya on ubuntu 14.10 through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXw7aPRASEk , and open the first time and after close and open again, shows this message

```
// Error: ... //
// Error: Line 0.147: Syntax error //
// Error: ... //
// Error: Line 0.140: Syntax error //
// Error: file: /usr/autodesk/maya/scripts/startup/HotboxMenus.mel line 157:  //
// mental ray for Maya 2014
// Mental ray for Maya: using startup file /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014//maya.rayrc.
// mental ray for Maya: setup
// mental ray for Maya: initialize
// mental ray for Maya: register extensions
// mental ray Node Factory: loaded
// mental ray for Maya: successfully registered
// mental ray for Maya: loading startup file: /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014//maya.rayrc
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/AdskShaderSDKWrappers.mi
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/abcimport.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/abcimport.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/architectural.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/architectural.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/base.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/base.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/builtin_bsdf.mi
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/contour.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/contour.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/paint.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/paint.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/physics.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/physics.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/production.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/production.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/ptex.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/ptex.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/subsurface.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/subsurface.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/surfaceSampler.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/surfaceSampler.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/userdata.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/userdata.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// parsing /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/include/useribl.mi
// loading /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/shaders/useribl.so
// generating Maya nodes...
// AbcExport v1.0 using Alembic 1.1.5 (built May 23 2013 13:10:17)
// AbcImport v1.0 using Alembic 1.1.5 (built May 23 2013 13:10:17)
// Error: line 1: Cannot find procedure "rebuildShowMenu". //
// Error: line 86: Cannot find procedure "buildDefaultHotBoxMenu". //
// Error: line 1: Object 'NEXDockControl' not found. //
// Error: line 1: Object '' not found. //
updateRendererUI;
// Error: file: /usr/autodesk/mentalrayForMaya2014/scripts/mentalrayUI.mel line 1313: menu: Object 'mainRenderMenu' not found. //
```

*How should I proceed?*